# IntelliJ, hotkey to use code under selection as parameter?

Tags: java, intellij-idea

One of those small things that tends to slow me down while coding...
How do you refactor code at your current position to become parameter of a new method call? Your cursor is `|`

`var foo = “|bar”;`

Now foo should be a File so I’d like:

`var foo = new File(“bar”);|`

How do you input “new File(“ and get the closing parentheses and semicolon generated by IntelliJ without moving around your cursor? Is Ctrl-W , cut , type , paste the fastest route?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may want to try the Complete Current Statement action (<kbd>Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd> on the Mac). It completes the current statement by adding any closing parentheses and semicolons as needed, no matter where in the statement your text cursor is positioned. You only have to type `new File(` in front and the `);` is added for you without moving the text cursor.

Another option may be to add your own Live Template. For example something like `$END$($SELECTION$)`. I named it "Surround with method call" and gave it the abbreviation `M`. Use it by first selecting the string constant and then invoking Surround with Live Template. It adds the parentheses and positions the text cursor in front of the opening parenthesis, and you can type `new File`.